# Is there a way to find "similar advertisers" without a Google AdSense account?

Tags: search-engines, google-adsense, advertising

I am trying to find ads that are similar to the ones suggested to me by Google Ads. Having done my research, I found that you can, as an advertiser, target "[similar audiences](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2676774?hl=en)" and that it is also possible, as an advertiser, to find competing advertisers.

Is there a way as a **user** to check on other ads Google Ads would show to the same audience group, other than just randomly searching Google and looking at ads?